# Не могу установить пакеты для Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Установил ST3 и Package Control сразу. Пытаюсь сделать `Package Control ⇒ Install Package` и получаю:

> Package Control
>
> There are no packages available for installation

Да быть такого не может, чтобы не было пакетов для установки.

Консоль ST3:

```
DPI scale: 1
startup, version: 3083 windows x64 channel: stable
executable: /C/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/sublime_text.exe
working dir: /C/Program Files/Sublime Text 3
packages path: /C/Users/Andrew/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Packages
state path: /C/Users/Andrew/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Local
zip path: /C/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/Packages
zip path: /C/Users/Andrew/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Installed Packages
ignored_packages: ["Vintage"]
pre session restore time: 0.0931
startup time: 0.1241
first paint time: 0.1241
reloading plugin Default.block
reloading plugin Default.comment
reloading plugin Default.copy_path
reloading plugin Default.delete_word
reloading plugin Default.detect_indentation
reloading plugin Default.duplicate_line
reloading plugin Default.echo
reloading plugin Default.exec
reloading plugin Default.fold
reloading plugin Default.font
reloading plugin Default.goto_line
reloading plugin Default.history_list
reloading plugin Default.indentation
reloading plugin Default.kill_ring
reloading plugin Default.mark
reloading plugin Default.new_templates
reloading plugin Default.open_context_url
reloading plugin Default.open_file_settings
reloading plugin Default.open_in_browser
reloading plugin Default.pane
reloading plugin Default.paragraph
reloading plugin Default.paste_from_history
reloading plugin Default.quick_panel
reloading plugin Default.save_on_focus_lost
reloading plugin Default.scroll
reloading plugin Default.set_unsaved_view_name
reloading plugin Default.side_bar
reloading plugin Default.sort
reloading plugin Default.swap_line
reloading plugin Default.switch_file
reloading plugin Default.symbol
reloading plugin Default.transform
reloading plugin Default.transpose
reloading plugin Default.trim_trailing_white_space
reloading plugin CSS.css_completions
reloading plugin Diff.diff
reloading plugin HTML.encode_html_entities
reloading plugin HTML.html_completions
reloading plugin 0_package_control_loader.00-package_control
reloading plugin Package Control.1_reloader
reloading plugin Package Control.2_bootstrap
reloading plugin Package Control.Package Control
plugins loaded
Package Control: Installing 1 missing dependency
Package Control: The dependency specified, bz2, is not available
Package Control: Skipping automatic upgrade, last run at 2016-01-04 17:18:36, next run at 2016-01-04 18:18:36 or after
reloading Packages/User/Package Control.sublime-settings
Package Control: Settings change detected, clearing cache
Package Control: Fetching list of available packages
  Platform: windows-x64
  Sublime Text Version: 3083
  Package Control Version: 3.1.2
Package Control: Download Debug
  URL: https://packagecontrol.io/channel_v3.json
  Timeout: 30
  Resolved IP: 50.116.33.29
Package Control: WinINet Debug Proxy
  proxy: 
  proxy bypass: 
  proxy username: 
  proxy password: 
Package Control: WinINet HTTPS Debug General
  Server SSL Certificate:
    subject: US, Massachusetts, Private Organization, 471714639, US, Massachusetts, Newbury, Codex Non Sufficit LC, codexns.io
    issuer: US, GeoTrust Inc., GeoTrust EV SSL CA - G4
    common name: codexns.io
    issue date: Thu, 29 Oct 2015 04:00:00 GMT
    expire date: Mon, 28 Nov 2016 03:59:59 GMT
Package Control: WinINet HTTPS Debug Write
  GET /channel_v3.json HTTP/1.1
  User-Agent: Package Control v3.1.2
  Host: packagecontrol.io
  Connection: Keep-Alive
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
  If-Modified-Since: Sun, 03 Jan 2016 15:20:01 GMT
Package Control: WinINet HTTPS Debug Read
  HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
  Server: nginx
  Date: Sun, 03 Jan 2016 15:27:35 GMT
  Last-Modified: Sun, 03 Jan 2016 15:20:01 GMT
  Connection: keep-alive
  ETag: "56893c21-5f"
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000
Package Control: Using cached content for https://packagecontrol.io/channel_v3.json from C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\Package Control.cache\01524fae79697630d0454ba3fabd9414
Package Control: WinINet HTTPS Debug General
  Closing connection to packagecontrol.io on port 443 after 1 request
```

Answer (score 7):

На момент написания вопроса сервера, которые используются *Package Control* для отдачи контента, находились под *DDoS* атакой. Вот тред на *GitHub*, в котором шла дискуссия по данной проблеме - [There are no packages available for installation: Package Control of Sublime Text 3](https://github.com/wbond/package_control/issues/959).

---

Если с Package Control случаются сбои, в его Твиттере публикуется информация, что происходит — https://twitter.com/package_control.

Также можно зайти в Issue Tracker данного менеджера пакетов: https://github.com/wbond/package_control/issues и посмотреть в новые issues. В ответах создателя Package Control Will Bond узнаёшь подробности, а главное, когда Package Control вновь начнёт функционировать. Если никто не открыл тему, можно сделать это самостоятельно.

---

Временное решение проблемы — открыть конфигурационный файл *Package Control*:

#### Вручную

> Preferences ⇒ Package Settings ⇒ Package Control ⇒ Settings - User

добавим туда альтернативный источник:

```
"channels":
[
    "https://packagecontrol.io/channel_v3.json",
    "https://web.archive.org/web/20160410055050/https://packagecontrol.io/channel_v3.json"
]
```

#### При помощи command palette

<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> → `Package Control: Add Channel` → вставляем https://web.archive.org/web/20160410055050/https://packagecontrol.io/channel_v3.json → <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Файл *channel_v3.json* содержит список всех плагинов и информацию о них, которую использует непосредственно сам *Package Control*. Первый адрес — оригинальный адрес, который используется по умолчанию; второй адрес с *web.archive.org* — альтернативный. К сожалению, регулярные периодические копии файла `channel_v3.json` на другой сервер не делаются (что не мешает Вам настроить периодическое копирование самостоятельно), поэтому приходится довольствоваться устаревшими копиями из Internet Archive.

#### Как получить альтернативный адрес

Открываем https://archive.org/web → вставляем в верхнее поле ввода адрес `https://packagecontrol.io/channel_v3.json`

[image: Package Control channel]

→ `BROWSE HISTORY` → выбираем самую свежую из сохранённых копий. На момент написания ответа это копия от 10 апреля 2016 года, копируем её URL — https://web.archive.org/web/20160410055050/https://packagecontrol.io/channel_v3.json — который вставляем, куда нужно, способами, описанными выше.

---

Почему решение временное. Когда в вашем конфигурационном файле содержится второй канал, даже после того, как нормальное функционирование Package Control возобновится, при попытке установить пакеты

- Вы не увидите новые пакеты, внесённые в Package Control после даты, когда на Internet Archive была сделана копия;
- Вы получите устаревшие версии пакетов — версии на тот момент, когда была сделана копия в Internet Archive;
- ни автоматическое обновление пакетов ни ручное — <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> → `Package Control: Upgrade/Overwrite All Packages` — не будет Вам доступно.

Поэтому через несколько дней — срок, когда нормальное функционирование Package Control обычно возобновляется — удалите дополнительный канал: <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> → `Package Control: Remove Channel` → выбираете внесённый Вами канал, который нужно удалить, → <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Если пакеты как и прежде не устанавливаются, смотрим, что там говорят в issue tracker, ссылка на который приведена выше.

---

Когда Package Contol не работает, а новые пакеты или обновления нужны, не забывайте, что новейшие версии всех пакетов, включая самые свежие, можно [**установить вручную**](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/Kristinita/SashaBooks/blob/master/IT/Sublime%20Text/Sublime%20Text%20Power%20User.pdf#page=16).

Comment: Michael Radionov, я серьёзно, более чем наполовину изменил и дополнил Ваш ответ. В случае несогласия автора так делать нельзя, поэтому можете откатить мои изменения. Если бы я написал свой ответ, его бы, наверное, снесли, поскольку он только дополнял бы Ваш. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, нет проблем, спасибо за исчерпывающее дополнение.